# C++ Struct Polymorphism for Arduino

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose there is a class called "Quadruped," in which there are two structures called "Femur" and "Crus." Both of these structs have two identical variables, an array of int's and a boolean. For one of the methods in the class Quadruped, I need to access the two variables in either Femur or Crus based on a condition given during runtime. This naturally leads me to create another structure called "Leg" from which the two structures Femur and Crus will inherit. Also, Leg would have to be virtual. Does this mean that I must create a dummy virtual function in Leg and define them in the two child structures to implement polymorphism? Would this be a valid use of struct polymorphism?

```
class Quadruped{  
  struct Leg{
    int[] channels;
    bool started;
    virtual void foo()=0;
  }
  struct Leg:Femur{
    int[] channels= {0, 1, 2, 3};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  }

  struct Leg:Crus{
    int[] channels= {4, 5, 6, 7};
    bool started= false;
    virtual void foo(){}
  }

  public:
  void bar(bool condition){
    Leg *myLeg;
    condition ? myLeg= new Femur() : myLeg= new Crus();
    someFunction(myLeg->channels[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an Arduino question its a C++ question (you might be using it on an Arduino, but ...) Try it on StackOverflow you'll get faster and possibly better answers on there.  (Ask a mod to move it, don't cross post)

Comment: How/Whom can I reach out to for moving the post to Stack OverFlow? Thank you.

Comment: What does the C++ compiler say about your code? Might need to check the syntax.

Comment: I apologize. I noticed a syntax error in the integer array declarations. After fixing them to int channels[4], the initial compiler error states "redefinition of 'struct Quadruped::Leg'" I've tried both single and double colons for the scope resolution. It appears that the compiler doesn't allow me to have inherited structs.

Comment: @Skipher `struct Femur : Leg { ...`

Comment: Do you want the post moved still, or is it resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can be compiled:

```
constexpr uint8_t SIZE = 4;

class Quadruped {
  struct Leg {
    bool           started = false;
    int8_t  channels[SIZE];

    Leg (int8_t i) {
      for (auto & chan : channels) { // init channels starting with i value
        chan = i++;
      }
    }

    virtual void foo()=0;
  };

  struct Femur : Leg {
    Femur(): Leg(0) {;}

    virtual void foo() {}
  };

  struct Crus : Leg {
    Crus(): Leg(4) {;}  // call Leg constructor with i=4     
    virtual void foo(){}
  };

public:
  void bar(bool condition) {
    Leg *myLeg;
    condition ? myLeg = new Femur() : myLeg = new Crus();
    //someFunction(myLeg->channels[0]);
  }
};
```

BUT: You have a memory leak in each call of method `Quadrupled::bar`!!!

Comment: I also need to call these two functions in order to start using the function bar. pwm.setPWMFreq(50); pwm.begin();. I tried placing these function calls in the public section of the class, but I get a compiler error saying that pwm does not name a type. These functions are from a library, and I've included the library header file. Where should I place these function calls?

Comment: @Skipher I'm not sure how do you want to use it. It might be array of PWMs in the Leg (instead of array of int8_t) and `chan.attach(i++)` or so. But I'm not aware of PWM in classes. You can use analogWrite with correct pin (but these are not available on UNO - at least not all of them)

Comment: The two functions come from a PWM/Servo driver library provided by Adafruit. Controlling servo motors with the driver requires calling functions to pwm. i.e. pwm.setPWM. However, to call setPWM, I must first setup the driver for use by calling pwm.begin() and pwm.setPWMFreq(). I do not wish to put these function calls in the function bar() as that would be unnecessarily repetitive

Comment: I apologize, there was an additional piece of code I was missing. Thank you